# Setting up odb in codeblocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks, odb

How would I setup odb in codeblocks??... There isn't a guide for the codeblocks ide on the odb website. I've tried using the guide for eclipse but I've been unable to set it up properly.

Comment: You'll have to dig [him](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ol%27_Dirty_Bastard) up first, [he](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ol%27_Dirty_Bastard) died like 10 years ago.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Shame on you, when you step through to... Brooklyn Zoo!

Comment: Guys.. Those answers aren't helpful